# Change Binding - Deploy .net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-deployment

I have a .net core application deployed to IIS. I already know how to deploy, but the base URL for my website is `localhost:5000/appapi/...` (appapi is alias name when I choose my site and add application).

This is my application configuration in IIS.

[image: Here is the pic]

This means if I want to access `home.cshtml`, the link will be `localhost:5000/appapi/home`. Every time I want to access any file in my project I always have to add "appapi" to the link by hand. How can I change the link or somehow I just don't need to add "appapi" to my link to be able to access my file?

Comment: So just to be clear, you want your website url to be `localhost:5000/appapi/home`, but the links inside your website generate the wrong url to other pages? Or do you want your url to be `localhost:5000/home`?

Comment: @gunr2171 I want my url work with just localhost:5000/home (without "appapi" in the middle) or at least when I click on href link in home.cshtml (for example: redirect to test.cshtml) The link automatically localhost:5000/appapi/test 'cause as I do it now the link is localhost:500/test and I have to add "appapi" by hand for the link to be able to work.

Answer (score 2):

Deploy it as a full fledged "Site" in IIS, rather than an application under the "Default" site. When you deploy it as an application under an existing site, you must have a virtual path (the `appapi` portion) to differentiate it from the site itself and any other applications deployed there.